# how to get css information with cefsharp

Tags: javascript, c#, html, cefsharp

I am develop a program that included CefSharp.
I want to get the CSS value of the element when a click in my program. Including sub-elements css information. However, the following problems occurred.

My code can not fetch subelements. I get that style, but it's not what I want.

```
if(message.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
{
    MM_BrowserController sd_browser = (MM_BrowserController)sender;
JavascriptResponse jsCss = await sd_browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("getComputedStyle(document.activeElement.parentNode);");
}
```

how to get css information.
i want "chrome dev tools" function ("select an element in the page to inspect it). i want css struct and style get

Comment: What if, just get `CSS` using `document.activeElement.parentNode.style.{style_property}` ?

Comment: document.activeElement.parentNode.style is not include subelement css information.  i want All css information get regardless of {style_property}

Comment: Every `node` has `style` in `JS`

Comment: I do not understand English very well. Sorry.

Comment: Nah, It's not problem :) Try to `console.log();` the element, you are selecting.. May be it is not selected: `console.log(document.activeElement.parentNode');`

Comment: thank. parentNode is selected. i get style. but not css struct. i want 
<div class='style1'>
    <div class='style2'>
    </div>
</div>
style1 and style2 in list

Comment: May be `c#` can't evauluate the script.. try `getComputedStyle(document.activeElement.parentNode)` in console.log

Comment: getComputedStyle (document.activeElement.parentNode) result example key:0 ,value:font-size and key:fontSize, value:12px, I parsing  is possible